# PHP Syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

I don't actually know what is wrong with the code. Here's the code and the error.

**Error**: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mday' (T_STRING), expecting ']' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calnedar.php on line 66

**Code**:

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon] !=$month) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']." &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>\n";
        $start += ADAY;
    }
}
```

---

Fixed initial error of ['mon'] now says "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calnedar.php on line 63"

Here's my code so far

```
<?php
define("ADAY", (60*60*24));
if (!checkdate($_POST['month'], 1, $_POST['year'])){
    $nowArray = getdate();
    $month = $nowArray['mon'];
    $year = $nowArray['year'];
} else {
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $POST['year'];
}
$start = mktime (12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year);
$firstDayArray = getdate($start);
?>
<html>
<head>
<title> Calendar </title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<? php echo "$_SERVER[PHP_SELF}"; ?>">
<select name="month">
<?php
$months = Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "October", "November", "December");
for ($x=1; $x<= count($months); $x++) {
    echo"<option value=\"$x\"";
    if ($x == $month) {
        echo " SELECTED";
    }
    echo ">".$months[$x-1]."";
}
?>
</select>
<select name="year">
<?php
for ($x=2014; $x<=2080; $x++) {
    echo "<option";
    if ($x == $year) {
        echo " SELECTED";
    }
    echo ">$x";
}
echo">$x";

?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value "Submit">
</form>
<br/>
<?php 
$days = Array("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat");
echo "<Table border=1 cellpadding=5><tr>\n";
foreach ($days as $day) {
    echo "<TD BGCOLOR=\"CCCCCC\" Align=center><strong>$day</strong></td>\n";
}
for ($count=0; $count <(6*7); $count++) {
    $dayArray = getdate($start);
    if (($count % 7) == 0) {
        if ($dayArray['mon'] != $month) {
            break;
        } else {
            echo "</tr><tr>\n";
            }
        }
 if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']." &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>\n";
        $start += ADAY;
    }
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is in `echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']." &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>\n";`

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Watch as everybody scrambles for a quick and easy one :p

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple syntax error.

Comment: Too specific, this is no debug site ^^

Comment: This question is off topic because syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon] !=$month) {
```

Sometimes its best to read the error and try to find out what it actually is trying to warn you. In this case it tells you that you quite possibly have a closing square bracket missing. In most cases its always the character before that is causing the problem.

So all you have to do is start from the beginning of your problem code character by character and notice where something is odd.

You'll notice in your `dayArray['mon]` there is a quote missing, and it should be like this `['mon']`

And that will solve your error

One way to prevent these errors is to be using a platform that can catch these errors for you in advance before compiling and uploading your code. Use a great IDE like Code 2 or NotePad++ to help you program efficiently

Comment: New Problem now in same section of code "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calnedar.php on line 63" Eg. first line of code

Comment: Ok bro, if you could EDIT your post and paste the code that you have now so that I can take a look, also paste the code block from line 60 to 65 or something to get the general idea of what your code looks like

Comment: Ok just mark my answer as correct then buddy! cheers, glad it worked for you

Comment: shall do(in 4 minutes), do you know how to fix my second error

Comment: the "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calnedar.php on line 63"

Comment: Ok great! as for your second problem, if you can paste that code block or whatever is around  line 64 

When looking at your code i've spotted something else, what is `ADAY` ? shouldnt that be `$ADAY` or something else?

Comment: Ive copied all of my code so far into my original question. Line 63 is the first line of my original small block of code

Comment: Well done buddy. I hear it was those two dots! im glad you were able to solve it. P.S. in future try to look at your code, double and triple check it all, maybe do a little research on what the errors actually mean, and if youre still not able to figure it out then use stackoverflow to gain an understanding but not to solve specific syntax errors. Please do go along with my suggestion and use an IDE such as Coda 2 or Notepad++ to help you program and spot these errors in advance for you.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax highlighter shows you  your error. You're missing a single quote. You're also using the scope resolution operator instead of `||` or `&&`:

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon] !=$month) {
```

should be

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] && $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
                                   ^^^^ HERE        ^^^ HERE
```

You should be using a text editor or IDE with syntax highlighting. They make catching these errors easier. Even the free ones like Notepad++ will do this well.

Comment: New Problem now in same section of code "Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\calnedar.php on line 63" Eg. first line of code

Comment: `$start += ADAY;` is almost certainly injcorrect. Did you mean `$ADAY`?

Comment: ^ yet still a problem

Comment: I believe it's the `::` in `if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon] !=$month) {` that's at fault. That should probably be `||` or a `&&` @user2902494

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you nailed it

Comment: thanks fred -ii- that was it *hero*

Comment: Depending on which condition the OP wants to check, an `OR` or an `AND` @JohnConde

Comment: Great, glad to hear it @user2902494

Comment: You will need to change your accepted answer, since this covered everything. @user2902494

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon] !=$month) {
//                                                   ^-- misssing '
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error:

this line

```
$dayArray['mon]
```

you need to close

```
$dayArray['mon']
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed a single quote after $dayArray['mon] and :: should be &&

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] && $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']." &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>\n";
        $start += ADAY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
if ($count < $firstDayArray['wday'] :: $dayArray['mon'] !=$month) {
    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
    } else {
        echo "<td>".$dayArray['mday']." &nbsp;&nbsp; </td>\n";
        $start+= ADAY;
    }
```

Comment: Try explaining the change you're proposing.  Code dumps with no explanation don't really help in the long run.

Comment: Acutally issue is missing code and 1 extra open braces in his code so I will fixed it.Okay soon Will try to post more details answered.